# vbs sometimes hangs during executing

Tags: cmd, vbscript, freeze, execution

I have vbs file myscript.vbs

```
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

outFile="c:\temp\txt.txt"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
objFile.Write "test" & vbCrLf
objFile.Close

Set objFSO=Nothing
```

when i executing it on Windows 7 x64 by calling

```
cscript //B //NOLOGO "myscript.vbs"
```

sometimes it not executing and in task manager there is cscript.exe proccess that does not terminate

also i try add //T:2 or use wscript but it behaves the same

this happens with other vbs scripts too

sfc /scannow found no errors

how can this be resolved?

Comment: The code that you posted is just an example or is the real example ??

Comment: Sounds like a software restriction policy (SRP), an application whitelist/blacklist tool (eg, Carbon Black, Applocker, Defendpoint, etc.), an anti-virus on-access scanner (eg, McAfee, TrendMicro, Kaspersky, etc.), or a poorly written hook (eg, Avecto, Citrix, etc.) may be interfering with your script.

Answer (score -1):

this is problem of windows. it is tests with new windows image on virual (no antivirus and some other thing). Create new image of virtual windows and it is work great. windows for some "skynet" reason behaves like this